# Python curses box() is made of 6s and 0s

Tags: python, terminal, curses, python-curses

So I ran into an interesting error/bug, I don't know which yet, but when running my Python curses script using the `box()` method I got the following result:[image: The result in question.]

The desired and expected out put is to be a normal box... made of lines.

Here is the code for the script:

```py
import curses
import init
import os
import time

MONSTER_LIST = init.init()
ENCOUNTER = []

def main(scr):

    curses.curs_set(0)

    scr.clear()
    h, w = scr.getmaxyx()

    get_number = "Number of players in party?"
    center_y, center_x = h//2, w//2 - len(get_number)//2
    scr.addstr(center_y, center_x, get_number)
    scr.refresh()
    NUMBER = int(scr.getstr())

    scr.clear()
    get_number = "Average rounded level of the Party"
    center_y, center_x = h//2, w//2 - len(get_number)//2
    scr.addstr(center_y, center_x, get_number)
    scr.refresh()
    LEVEL = int(scr.getstr())

    y = h-1

    bottom_text = "[S]earch [H]omebrew, S[A]ve, [Q]uit"

    FLAG = True

    scr.clear()

    encounter_y, encounter_x = h-2, w-2
    while FLAG:

        scr.addstr(0,0, 'D&D Encounter Builder')
        scr.addstr(y,0, bottom_text)
        Encounter_window = curses.newwin(encounter_y, encounter_x,1,1)
        encounter_box_y, encounter_box_x = Encounter_window.getmaxyx()
        Encounter_window.box(encounter_box_y, encounter_box_x)
        Encounter_window.addstr(1,2, 'Encounter list')
        Encounter_window.addstr(encounter_box_y-3, 2, f"Difficulty = {init.cr_calculation(NUMBER, LEVEL, ENCOUNTER)}")
        scr.refresh()
        Encounter_window.refresh()

        CHOICE = scr.getch()

        FLAG = False

curses.wrapper(main)
```

If this helps, I am using Arch 5.9.8-arch1-1 and I am using st-256 for my terminal emulator.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.box) feature of curses which the Python binding uses:

> **window.box**([*vertch*, *horch*])
>
> Similar to **border**(), but both *ls* and *rs* are *vertch* and both *ts* and *bs* are *horch*. The default corner characters are always used by this function.

Your example isn't setting the box **size**, but instead the **characters** used to draw it.

The character "0" has the value 48.  Actually your horizontal characters aren't 0's, but probably

```
216    Ø
```

If you're seeing 6's for the vertical character, that is because the character for "6" happens to be 48 (0) + 6 = 54.

Comment: Thank you, I am glad it is that i was using the package wrong and that it was not finicky.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm.

Turns out, this is a weird bug with curses that I haven't seen documented yet. If you give the `box()` method the dimensions of the window you are working with, it wigs out and doesnt know how to draw itself.

The simple solution is:

```py
        Encounter_window.box(encounter_box_y, encounter_box_x)
```

to

```py
        Encounter_window.box()
```

This seems really finicky and strange to me, so I would like some one to explain what is going on here.

Thanks anyways.